# Strange behaviours of pointer to constant in C

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I have some questions about strange behaviours of pointer to constant in C.

1.

```
int x = 1;
const int *ptr = &x; 
x = 2;
printf("%d %d",*ptr, x);
```

Since pointer ptr points to const int, I expected an error in the third line. (Because "1" is already saved in the pointer ptr and the value in the pointer cannot change since I have added "const"!)

2.

```
double rates[3] = {0.1,0.2,0.3};
const double *ptr = rates;
ptr[2] = 99.99;
```

From the second line, ptr is the address of rates[0]. I expected no error to occurs from the third line since only *ptr = rates[0] is const double!

Why does such things happen?

Comment: You can't change the value of x from ptr, but you can change it from x. x is not const. The value of your pointer never changed. The value your pointer *points to* changed. The address of an apartment didn't change. Who lives in that apartment did.

Comment: In the first example, if you din't have `ptr` would you expect the `x = 2` assignment to fail? Why not? Why would you expect it to fail just because you add another *unrelated* variable? In the second example, you do the opposite of the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember

```
const double *ptr; // Remember it like (const double) <- *ptr;
```

means `ptr` is pointing to `const double`, which just means you *can't use  pointer itself* to change the data pointed to. However if the original data itself is not constant, you may use any other agent to modify the value like you did in

**Case 1**

```
const int *ptr = &x; 
x = 2; // You use x itself to change the value
```

> Since pointer ptr points to const int, I expected an error in the
>   third line.

You won't get an error, because you're not changing x through pointer.
If  you do

```
*ptr=2; //you get an error
```

Now for
**Case 2**

> I expected no error to occurs from the third line

```
const double *ptr = rates;
ptr[2] = 99.99;
```

This is the opposite of the first case, you used pointers to change constant data,
Had the line been

```
rates[2] = 99.99;
```

you would have got no errors.

Answer (score 3):

`x` is not `const`. So `x = 2;` is OK.

`const int *ptr;` does not mean "ptr points to const int".  It means "ptr may point to an `int` which may or may not be const; and you are not allowed to use `*ptr` to write to that `int`."

> Because "1" is already saved in the pointer ptr

No, the thing saved in the pointer is the address of a memory location. `1` is saved in the memory location that the pointer holds the address of.

> only *ptr = rates[0] is const double

That makes no sense. `ptr[2]` means `*(ptr + 2)`  ; and using `+ 2` on a `const double *` yields another `const double *` pointing to a different memory location.

Answer (score 1):

Const simply tells the compiler not to allow you to directly change the value of that variable. It does not make it impossible to change it. You can still change the value with pointers, like you did.

When you use const with pointers, you simply tell the compiler not to allow you do change the value of that pointer, not the value stored in the array.

Comment: I hope that makes sense, if it`s too confusing let me know and I will give you some reading material on it.